# default mysql.sock

Tags: sockets, mysql, serversocket

I'm using mysql and mysqldump and I'm using MAMP.

I have to put --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock in every CLA mysql commands

How can I use mysql command in CLI without using that boring line (--socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock) ?

Ho yes, I'm on OSX.

Thanks to read me

Answer (score 0):

search your my.conf file, and check the socket path in it :

```
...
[mysqld]
socket=/path/to/socket
...
```

(First hit for "mysql config socket path" [google search](https://www.google.fr/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=mysql%20config%20socket%20path))

Comment: Thanks for the ask, but there is no my.conf on OSX dude

Comment: Read this : http://www.comentum.com/mysql-administration.html. My.cnf is not created automatically, since its default values are hardcoded.